# Log in with facebook in Android app withount the need of the facebook app

Tags: php, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to add a login with facebook button in my android app, and than store the user information in a php server.
When following the [official documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.3) I found out that the SDK user the facebook app, so pepole who will use my app will have to install the facebook app first and I dont want that dependence, and I couldn't find a documentation that teaches how to implement that. 
Obviously I m just a beginner so please help me with that, thanks in advance.

Comment: Just live with it.  Facebook doesn't allow you to login without their app on your phone.    If you don't want that, don't use facebook for login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SDK only, as it provides both functionalities. If user has Facebook app installed in his phone, than it will login from the app. If user does not have Facebook installed on his phone, then FacebookSdk will automatically open a login dialog for Facebook login.

[image: Check this image]

Comment: can u share with me some code, cause I m a newby :D

Comment: You can check this link [Facebook Login](http://javatechig.com/android/using-facebook-sdk-in-android-example)